# Curve has no vertices when converted to a mesh

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to make a curved plane using a bezier object, however when I do ALT+C and press "Mesh from curve/meta/surf/text" and go into edit mode, there are no vertices on the object.

Bezier curve in edit mode before converting it
[image: Bezier curve in edit mode before converting it]

Curve in edit mode after converting it (no vertices)
[image: Curve in edit mode after converting it (no vertices)]

Any reasons as to why this is happening? (It worked fine on another curve I was working on when I first started the project)

Comment: If the 2nd pic is in Edit mode, it appears the object is just a line not a plane as such.  Also it's edges are all highlited which can confuse the view somewhat.  Press A to clear the selection and then CTL-TAB --> Vertices to see the points it should have.

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I was in edge select mode instead of vertex