# Bezier curve converted to mesh - either no vertices or all a vertex?

Tags: bezier-curves, 3d-printing

I have four curves in the screenshots, but I'm focused on just the upper left one. Here, it's a Bezier curve. I've selected it, then I right-clicked and picked "Convert to Mesh."
[image]
Then I went into Edit Mode and no vertices were selected. In fact, no vertices were visible:
[image]
I searched and found [this question asking the same thing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/139881/101310). So I tried pressing A to get all vertices to appear and I get this (still in edit mode):
[image]
I thought, "Well, maybe it's got so many vertices that it looks like one long line." I zoomed in. No. Just the line is highlighted, but there are no vertices on it. I tried to use Box Select to see if I could select a few vertices, but I couldn't select anything. Since my goal was to go on and make a prism out of this form (to use as a boolean modifier), I pressed <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and nothing happened. I'm not sure if I can extrude from a line, so I turned all 4 curves in the screenshot into meshes, then joined them together into one mesh. I went to Edit Mode, hit <kbd>A</kbd> and moved my pointer as if I were extruding and there was no extrusion. The entire shape moved instead.

Why don't I see individual vertices in Edit Mode and why can't I extrude from this mesh I've created?

Comment: You are probably in Edge or Face select mode ... Switch to Vertex select mode (left top header).

Comment: @vklidu I was stuck in Face Select from earlier today. First time I've used it so I had completely forgotten about it. If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll select it and upvote it.

Comment: Thank you for offer, I'm not going to create Answer ... Great it solved your issue. Happy blending :)

Comment: You "hit A and moved [your] pointer as if [you] were extruding" - but did you hit E again before extruding? A itself will only select. There must be something missing in your description... as I commented to you on another question, it usually doesn't matter which select mode your in, no matter if vertex or edge select, the extrusion should work. (Of course face select doesn't work in this case - no faces, nothing to select.) If it's not extruding although you have a mesh object in _Edit Mode_ and selected something I don't see why it shouldn't extrude anything.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes. I hit A to select all, then hit E after that to extrude. I'll clear that up tomorrow after I've had some sleep. When you pointed out I needed to use a different mode for selecting, that's the first time I had used that (that I remember!). That made it easy for me to forget what selection mode I was in. But when I changed to vertices, it worked. Another point - at the time when I was dealing with this, the object was an outline - no face and I was using Face select. Makes perfect sense now, didn't then!

Comment: @Tango But in the last picture it looks as if the curve in the top left **is** selected (if it really is in _Edit Mode_), so there you must have been in _Edge Select_ mode. In this case you shouldn't have to change anything, extruding should have been possible.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I selected by pressing A, but, believe it or not, it was in Face Select. Weird, then. Not sure what was happening there. (Also, somewhere along the line, I tend to lock things down and have to click the Snap icon at the top so I can move things again. At some point I'll have time to look that up and see how I accidentally trigger it. But that just shows how, as I learn new things, or in my general work, I hit the wrong key or click something and forget about it and end up with Blender in a mode I'm not used to or don't fully understand.

Comment: @Tango Well, at least I learned something new after so many years. I actually didn't know that... although it's not possible to select anything in _Face Select_ by clicking on it or pressing L while hovering your mouse over it when there are no faces and even vertex or edge selections get lost when switching from the other selecting modes to _Face Select_, nevertheless pressing A selects everything even without faces. Never bothered to do that, because the other way round it doesn't work.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks for including that so I could learn it, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have obviously switched the *Select Mode* to *Faces* by mistake.

[image]

If you switch it to *Vertices*, everything should work as expected.

PS: I still wonder why you don't solve this task procedurally, though, because that would have saved you a lot of your precious time by now:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/268162/145249 ;-)

Comment: Even though I've done a few different projects, I'm quite new at Blender. I'm also having to learn slicing software for 3D printing and for CNC work - and there are differences between slicing for printers and CNC. Plus I'm learning a lot of the tricks and intricacies of 3 1/2 machines (2 printers, 1 CNC, plus a laser etcher on the CNC). That's a lot to learn at once. Plus, one thing I learned back when I was a special ed teacher, I have a different learning style and curve than most people.

Comment: I don't think you realize how complex your answer is to a new person. Eventually, when I have the full process worked out, I'll likely write a Python script to automate it. For now, though, the critical part is making sure I can produce an end result. And, as I learned in my education classes for special ed, people have different learning styles. What works for one person does not always work for others.

Comment: @Tango You might be right that I am a bit "blind" when it comes to *Geometry Nodes*. However, I always try to convey the possible solution in a simple and understandable way, so that you can learn from it in the best possible way. So please bear with me. But I also want to encourage you: *Geometry Nodes* are easier than they look, and you will get along with them relatively quickly once you get involved.

Comment: I'm not arguing that your solution doesn't work or that you haven't done a good job of writing it up, but at this point, it doesn't work for me. I used to run a data mining business, mostly written in Perl (that should tell you how long ago it was - Perl was respectable at the time!). When I sat down to start writing it, I had not written a line of code in over a decade, probably longer. But I had people willing to pay for data, so it was a case of, "Get it done and get the data out there."

Comment: Before I could get the system going so I could quickly send customers data (instead of going through a ton of steps to produce the files I'd send them), I didn't have time to learn a lot of things that would have made the job easier and take less time. Once I got it working, and could define the steps involved, I could finally sit and plan the overall system - which used many concepts I didn't even know about when I started the whole thing. I've used nodes in the past, but I won't have time to do a dive into that topic (or others) for 6 months or so - after I know what it'll all look like.

Comment: As commented above, after all these years I learned something new... 'A' selects everything in every select mode, even vertices/edges in _Face Select_ when there aren't any faces.